# How to replace a function with unknown argument names?

Tags: php, arguments

This is what I want to do:

```
$var = "foo";  
$unknown = "";  
function do($arg1, $arg2) {  
    $arg2 = "bar";
    magic($arg2);
    }  
do($var, $unknown);  
echo $unknown;
```

This should return: bar

I know that this would work if I'd define my function like this:

```
function do($arg1, $unknown) {
    global $unknown;
    $unknown = "bar";
}
```

As you probably guessed already, the variable name of $unknown is unknown.

I need this because I'm writing a PHP sandbox using apd. I want to replace exec($cmd, $ret)  in a PHP script I don't known with my own function.

So if the unknown PHP script looks like this:

```
$foo = "";
exec('whois google.com', $foo);
echo $foo;
```

I'll have a problem replacing exec with my own function do() emulating the same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [pass the parameter by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
$var = "foo";  
$unknown = "";  
function foo($arg1, &$arg2) {    // NOTE EXTRA "&"
    $arg2 = "bar";
}  
foo($var, $unknown);  
echo $unknown;
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/7fHdE)**.

Comment: Looks good! But it doesn't work if foo($var, $unknown); get's included. I'm running my sandbox like this: php sandbox.php unknown.php and sandbox.php contains include $argv[1]; at the end. Suggestions?